# Private declared but doesn't accept variable

Tags: java, class, get, set, private

I have declared my variables as private and wanted to use note on the class noter like here:

```
public class Etudiant {
    private String nom , prenom ;
         private int anneeNais, LIMITE=60;
         private double note;
         private String code ;
```

And this is the class for it:

```
 public class GroupeEtudiant {

    final int MAX=20;  
 Etudiant[] etudiants = new Etudiant[MAX];
 int nbreEtudiants  ;



 public void ajouterEtudiant(Etudiant unEtudiant){

 etudiants[nbreEtudiants]=unEtudiant;
 nbreEtudiants ++;
}

        public void SetNoter(int i, double uneNote) { 
       etudiants[i].getNote=uneNote;
  }
```

it says note has private access in Etudiant

Comment: this class doesn't even compile as your GroupeEtudiant references a field called getNote which doesn't exist.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy yeah well if you see the object Etudiant takes it from there

Comment: I don't think you are distinguishing properly between members and methods.

Comment: @SteveHarris well I'm learning and the teacher said to do it like this

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw did

Answer (score 0):

> it says note has private access in Etudiant

that's due to the reason that `note` is a private field to the class `Etudiant` hence it's not visible or accessible outside of the class, rather make a `getter` & `setter` methods for it inside `Etudiant` class.

**Note** - in your case you don't necessarily need a `getter` but it's a good practice to provide them when you declare fields as private.

*Example:*

inside `Etudiant` class, create a `getNote` field like this:

```
public double getNote(){
    return this.note;
}
```

also a `setNote` field inside the class:

```
public void setNote(double note){
    this.note = note;
}
```

*assuming you've done the suggestions above, simply replace this:*

```
public void SetNoter(int i, double uneNote) { 
      etudiants[i].getNote=uneNote;
}
```

*with this:*

```
public void SetNoter(int i, double uneNote) { 
      etudiants[i].setNote(uneNote);
}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but it doesn't work I am sending a google drive link of code so you can see: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T_K6NYwcc0USamZHuRlYSd8vZR49h-5gex1imFnEl80/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @studentofjava the solution i have provided works 100%. If you need any further help feel free to update your post and not external links.

Comment: @studentofjava I only need you to update the Etudiant class with the suggestions i have provided and I will see from there on.

Comment: well I did what you asked when I tried to post here it got refused

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to assign a value to a methode inside `SetNoter()`:

```
public void SetNoter(int i, double uneNote) { 
    etudiants[i].getNote=uneNote;
}
```

You should rather pass `uneNote` as an argument to it ( if the method `public void setNote( double note )` actually exists ):

```
etudiantes[i].setNote( uneNote );
```

UPDATE:

To access a **private** member variable you should use public methods 
( so called getter and setter ):

```
public class Etudiant {

    private String nom , prenom ;
        private int anneeNais, LIMITE=60;
        private double note;
        private String code;

    // for reading the variable
    public double getNote() {
        return this.note;
    }

    // for setting the variable
    public void setNote( double uneNote ) {
        this.note = uneNote;
    }

}
```

Then you can use the `setNote()` method to set the variable like mentioned above.